# Get know to consumed resources by a virtual directory

Tags: c#, iis, resources, application-pool, virtual-directory

I have many applications on IIS in different web sites.
Some of them are using 4 core some of them are using just 1 core of CPU. To make this I seperated into different application pools (named like 4.0Framework_1CPU, 3.5Framework_4CPU etc.)

I want to get know which virtual directory is consuming how much ram, cpu, disk space real time.
And how can I get these information programmatically to make alerts?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not possible to monitor resources consumed by individual virtual directories, though for application pools running .NET Framework 4 you can enable monitoring of individual applications by enabling [AppDomain.MonitoringIsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.monitoringisenabled.aspx?queryresult=true) property.

For application pools running older version of .NET framework, you can only monitor resources on per-process (per application pool) basis. For this purpose you can use classes from [System.Web.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.aspx) namespace (especially [WebProcessStatistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.webprocessstatistics.aspx)), or get data regarding ASP.NET from [PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx)s.